# Tosca puzzle 94441 solved with RBFW , TESTING METHODS) - cannot be converted to SelectAttribute

Tags: testing, browser, robotframework, tosca

This range/series is about test automation. The show the CEO's and managers of this world (in a later moment when all work is done) what exactly the difference is between Tosca and f.e. RobotFrameWork.

The results will be on Youtube just like FlurFunk did with Tosca. ( https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCR5i6k5emJ6hxox-iQcv85Q )

But in some cases I get stuck and I need some help from the community.

This puzzle is about clicking a button until the name changes https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/94441

What I got so far is:

```
    *** Settings ***
# https://robotframework-browser.org/
Library   Browser
Library    String
#Library  Tables
#Title is:  TESTING METHODS

*** Variables ***
@{LIST}   | Functional | End2End | GUI testing | Exploratory Testing |

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test 70310
    Browser.OPEN BROWSER  https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/94441
    Select Options By    value   select[id='multiselect']   Functional    End2End    GUI testing    Exploratory Testing
    Get Text         xpath=//body    *=   You solved this automation problem.
    # used resources
```

which results in:

```
ValueError: Argument 'attribute' got value 'select[id='multiselect']' that cannot be converted to SelectAttribute: SelectAttribute does not have member 'select[id='multiselect']'. Available: 'index', 'label', 'text' and 'value'
```

Answer (score 1):

finally got it to work. but... I wasn't able to find a way with the 'Browser' library... so I had to make use of 'SeleniumLibrary'

after lots of tries this resulted in the | PASS |

```
 OPEN BROWSER  https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/94441       
    SET BROWSER IMPLICIT WAIT    3
    SeleniumLibrary.SELECT FROM LIST BY LABEL        id=multiselect    Functional testing    End2End testing    GUI testing    Exploratory testing
    SET BROWSER IMPLICIT WAIT    3
```

it explicitly had to be 'by label' that was the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Order of arguments is important unless they're named. This should work with Browser Lib -

```
Select Options By    select[id='multiselect']   value   Functional    End2End    GUI
```